# Dataframe convert Values in row into a unique column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, encoding, boolean-logic

I've got a categorical column called `outcome category` which shows different types of outcomes for crimes i.e:

`{Investigation complete; no suspect identified,  Local resolution, Unable to prosecute suspect, Awaiting court outcome,  Formal action is not in the public interest, Offender given penalty notice,  Under investigation}`
\
From the column, I would like to extract where values = `Awaiting court outcome, Under investigation`

and make a new column `Arrests` signifying true or false where these values arise in the `outcome` column

Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask is a really good guide to show how to ask a good question.  It usually shows an example of the input data, some code that you have made to solve the problem, and the desired outcome.  With this people will understand what you want and be able to help.

Comment: What is the data type of your `outcome category` column? Edit your question with the result of `type(df.iloc[0, 'outcome category'])`

Comment: The column is of a categorical type

Comment: `df['outcome'] = df['outcome category'].apply(lambda x : 'Awaiting court outcome' in x or 'Under investigation' in x)`